# Can't pass 2nd environment variable with execve

Tags: c, execve

I would like to display 2 environment variables that are passed as argument to another process using execve() function:

Main.c:

```
int main(){


    char USERNAME[10];
    strcpy(USERNAME, "USERNAME=");
    for (int i=1;i<10;i++){
        strcpy(USERNAME+i, "1");
    }

    char PATH[169];
    strcpy(PATH, "PATH=");
    for (int i=5;i<169;i++){
        strcpy(PATH+i, "A");
    }


    char * newargv[] = {"./get","", (char*)0};
    char * newenviron[] = {PATH,USERNAME};
    execve("./get", newargv, newenviron);
    return 0;
}
```

get.c:

```
int main()
{
    const char* s = getenv("PATH");
    printf("PATH :%s\n",s);
    const char* s2 = getenv("USERNAME");
    printf("USERNAME :%s\n",s2);
}
```

So I compile Main.c to Main and get.c to get, and execute Main, I get this output:

> PATH
>   :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   USERNAME :(null)

I don't understand why USERNAME is NULL here.

Comment: You could try doing `printf("<%s>\n", USERNAME);` inside the loop of your first program. You will see that it does not contain what you think. Or even better, learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @WeatherVane Huh? `strcpy` is what initializes it.

Comment: @JosephSible mybad, but still, the last `strcpy` in the loop will overrun the array, because of the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: Closely related to [Can't pass properly environment with `execve()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635818/cant-pass-properly-environment-with-execve-function) by user [juRioqs75](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7457216/jurioqs75).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a null terminator on the end of your `newenviron` array. Also, you're writing one more byte to each string than you've allocated space for (the ending \0 counts as a character).

Comment: You mean like `char * newenviron[] = {PATH,USERNAME,NULL};` ? It does not work...

Comment: Yes, you need to do that. What does "does not work" mean? What exactly happened when you did it? And did you fix your string sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Oups my bad, I erased the "USERNAME=" part of the USERNAME tab, because loop started from **1** instead of **9**...

Comment: arf ! the second printf display USERNAME but **also** PATH, how to prevent this ?

Comment: As already been told to you, you are missing to tailing zero `\0`